# Is it possible to automatically post something on a company's Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I'm looking to add more functionality to the Share button essentially. What I'd like to do is when someone is sharing a blog post from my site, it automatically inserts a pre-populated message addressing the company that the blog post was about. 
So if I write about McDonalds, the blog post could be shared with a message like "Hey @McDonalds, check out this post".
Any ideas? Is this even allowed based on their TOS?

Comment: What sort of information did you get from your initial research? What does your current code look like?

Comment: Not, it is not allowed to pre-fill _anything_ that you post in the user’s name – any content has to be actively created by the users themselves.